# Android - How to throw an Exception that I don't want to handle

Tags: java, android, exception, throw

I'm creating a reusable fragment in my project.

I want to force the calling Fragment to send the reference through a `Bundle` so I can get it with `getArguments()`.

How to throw an Exception that I don't want to handle, so I'll force the implementation?

This is how I planed to do it:

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    String callerFragment = bundle.getString(COMMON_COMPONENT_CALLER_TAG);
    if(callerFragment == null){
        throw new UnknownCallerException("Missing caller name");
    }
```

Comment: Just throw a RuntimeException... What's the problem with this code?

Comment: Using RuntimeException solves the problem. Android Studio forces to handle the custom Exception.

Comment: You can extend RuntimeException, if you wish